# I am trying to make an AJAX request in laravel but it gives me the error "422 (Unprocessable Content)"

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, routes, crud

I am trying to make CRUD with AJAX request here. I can display the data from the database. But when I try to add data to it it's giving me the error
"The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods : GET, HEAD".
Give me a solution. I am just a newbie in laravel.

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('projects',[ProjectController::class, 'index']) -> name('projects.index');
    Route::get('project-list', [projectController::class, 'list']);
    Route::post('project-add', [projectController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('project-view', [projectController::class, 'show']);
    Route::get('project-delete', [projectController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::post('project-edit', [projectController::class, 'update']);
```

This is my store function in controller (ProjectController)

```
public function store(ProjectStoreRequest $request)
    {
        $deadline = Carbon::parse($request->deadline)->format('Y-m-d');
        $project = [
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description'=> $request->description,
            'deadline' => $deadline,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'client_id' => $request->client_id,
        ];
        $data = Project::create($project);
        if($data){
            $response = [
                'status'=>'ok',
                'success'=>true,
                'message'=>'Record created succesfully!'
            ];
            return $response;
        }else{
            $response = [
                'status'=>'ok',
                'success'=>false,
                'message'=>'Record created failed!'
            ];
            return $response;
        }

}
```

This is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h1>Projects</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                            @can('projects.write')
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-toggle = "modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "create"><i
                                            class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a></li>
                            @endcan
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                @if (session('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('success') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Client Name</th>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class = "projectdata">
                    {{-- @php
                        // get current page for Paginator
                        $currentPage = (\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage() - 1) * 10;
                    @endphp
                    @foreach($projects as $key => $project)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $currentPage + $key + 1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $project->title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $project->description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $project->client->name ?? '-' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($project->deadline)->format('Y-m-d') ?? '-' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $project->status }}</td>
                             <td>
                                @canany(['projects.write', 'projects.read'])
                                    <a href="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Show</a>
                                @endcan
                                @can('projects.write')
                                    <a href="{{ route('projects.edit', $project->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                    <form action="{{ route('projects.destroy', $project->id) }}" method="post" class="d-inline">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                @endcan
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach --}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {{-- <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    {{ $projects->links('pagination::bootstrap-4') }}
                </div> --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id = "csrf" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" id = "title" class="form-control">
                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <div class="text-danger" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Description</label>
                            <textarea name="description" id = "description" rows="5" cols="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            @if ($errors->has('description'))
                                <div class="text-danger" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Deadline:</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="deadline" data-target-input="nearest">
                                <input type="date" id = "deadline" name="deadline" class="form-control" data-target="#deadline"/>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('deadline'))
                                <div class="text-danger" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{ $errors->first('deadline') }}</div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Status</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
                                <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
                                <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                                <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                            </select>
                            @if ($errors->has('status'))
                                <div class="text-danger"
                                     style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Select Client</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="client_id" id="clients_list">
                                @foreach($clientUsers as $client)
                                    <option value="{{ $client->id }}">{{ $client->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            @if ($errors->has('client_id'))
                                <div class="text-danger"
                                     style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{ $errors->first('client_id') }}</div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
                            <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "save">Add</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            projects();
        });
        function projects(){
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                url : "{{url('project-list')}}",
                success : function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var tr = '';
                    for(var i = 0;i<response.length;i++){
                        var title = response[i].title;
                        var description = response[i].description;
                        var clientname = response[i].client.name;
                        var deadline = response[i].deadline;
                        var status = response[i].status;
                        tr += '<tr>';
                        tr += '<td>' + (i+1) + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' +title + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + description + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + clientname + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + deadline + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + status + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td><div class = "justify-content-around">'
                        tr += '<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "btn btn-primary">Show</a>'
                        tr += '<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "btn btn-primary">Edit</a>'
                        tr += '<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "btn btn-danger">Delete</a>'
                        tr += '</div></td>'
                    }
                    console.log(tr);
                    $('.projectdata').html(tr);
                }
            });
        }
$('#save').click(function(){
            addProject();
});
        

function addProject(){
            var title = $('#title').val();
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var deadline = $('#deadline').val();
            var status = $('#status').val();
            var client = $('#clients_list').val();
            var token = $('#csrf').val();
            console.log(client);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    deadline: deadline,
                    status: status,
                    client_id: client,
                    _token: token
                },
                url: "{{ url('project-add') }}",
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                    projects();
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

As given in the comments I didn't called the addProject() function first. It's my carelessness I am sorry. But now when I run this it's giving me the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Content)
```

Thank you guys for your comments. I fixed this issue by replacing "ProjectStoreRequest" with "Request" thus ignoring the Requests/ProjectStoreRequest file. Thank you for being kind

Comment: To be  clear...you are talking about the code in `function addProject()`, yes? If so please reduce your question to just a [mre] of the issue. If other functions are not relevant to the error, don't include them. See also [ask]. Then it's easier for us to see what's relevant.

Comment: P.S. I don't actually see any code which would trigger the `addProject` function to be called in your page though. So maybe that's not what you're talking about? It's not very clear. You told us an error but didn't explain what actions or code in your had led to it. Maybe it's caused by one of the forms in your page? Again, please reduce down the code to just the bits which are directly related to the issue you're having, then there's no confusion.

Comment: Which route is affected? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I am really sorry I didn't called the function at all. I am really sorry it's my carelessness. When I try to call the function now, it results in this error in the console.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Comment: Which is "the function"? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: 422 errors are usually validation errors. Some rule(s) in the `ProjectStoreRequest` must be failing and if you look at the response body, it should show what those errors are.